# Openedge 4gl Display 2 For each?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Let's say I have 2 for each statement with 2 none related table
The first one is

```
for each table-1 
   disp table-1.col1 
        table-1.col2.
end. 

for each table-2
   disp table-2.col1
        table-2.col2.
end.
```

and it displays to me like this

```
table-1.col1 table-1.col2 
table-1.col1 table-1.col2
table-1.col1 table-1.col2

table-2.col1 table-2.col2
table-2.col1 table-2.col2
table-2.col1 table-2.col2
```

I would like it to display like this

```
---------- Table 1 ---------      ---------- Table 2 --------
|table-1.col1 table-1.col2 |      |table-2.col1 table-2.col2|      
|table-1.col1 table-1.col2 |      |table-2.col1 table-2.col2|
|table-1.col1 table-1.col2 |      |table-2.col1 table-2.col2|
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the tables are unrelated you'll have to do some data manipulation to get the side-by-side chart output you're looking for. You can create a "line" temp table that holds the four fields you want to show across each output line. Go through each of the tables, adding the record data to each line. Then go through the line temp table and output the line data.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE linecnt AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttLine
    FIELD linenum AS INTEGER
    FIELD tbl1col1 AS CHARACTER
    FIELD tbl1col2 AS CHARACTER
    FIELD tbl2col1 AS CHARACTER
    FIELD tbl2col2 AS CHARACTER
    INDEX Idx1 IS PRIMARY linenum.

linecnt = 1.  /* Initialize the line counter. */

/* Go thru table-1, creating a ttLine for each record. */
FOR EACH table-1 NO-LOCK:
    CREATE ttLine.
    ASSIGN
        ttLine.linenum = linecnt
        ttLine.tbl1col1 = table-1.col1 
        ttLine.tbl1col2 = table-1.col2
        linecnt = linecnt + 1.
END. 

linecnt = 1.  /* Reset the line counter. */

/* Go thru table-2, adding data to ttLine and creating new records if necessary. */
FOR EACH table-2 NO-LOCK:
    FIND FIRST ttLine WHERE ttLine.linenum = linecnt NO-ERROR.
    IF NOT AVAILABLE(ttLine) THEN
    DO:
        CREATE ttLine.
        ttLine.linenum = linecnt.
    END.

    ASSIGN
        ttLine.tbl2col1 = table-2.col1
        ttLine.tbl2col2 = table-2.col2
        linecnt = linecnt + 1.
END.

/* Go thru ttLine, output data. */
OUTPUT TO VALUE("output.txt").

PUT UNFORMATTED
    "---------- Table 1 ---------      ---------- Table 2 --------"
    SKIP.

FOR EACH ttLine:
    PUT UNFORMATTED
        "|" + 
        STRING(ttLine.tbl1col1, "X(12)") + " " + STRING(ttLine.tbl1col2, "X(12)") + 
        " |      |" +
        STRING(ttLine.tbl2col1, "X(12)")  + " " + STRING(ttLine.tbl2col2, "X(12)") + 
        "|" 
        SKIP.
END.

OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

The above example should give you the output you're looking for. It will also handle situations where you don't have the same number of records in each table. It will leave blank spaces where there is no data.

Comment: No, you can set the placement yourself. See the answer from Mike.

Answer (score 4):

If you specify the width and col(umn) for the two frames, you can control that they should be displayed next to each other.

```
for each Salesrep:                                                                      
   display salesrep.salesrep                                                            
           salesrep.repname                                                             
       with down frame frm-salesrep                                                     
       width 40.                                                                        
end.                                                                                    

for each Item:                                                                          
    display item.ItemNum                                                                
            item.ItemName                                                               
       with down frame frm-item                                                         
       col 41.                                                                                    
end.
```